# My String has embedded byte string - Python

Tags: python, string, amazon-s3, utf-8, byte

Currently reading from s3 and saving within a dataframe.

Problem image:

[image]

S3 objects are read in as bytes however it seems within my string, the byte string is also there.
Unable to decode a string using - example_string.decode().

Another problem from this is trying to find emojis within the text. These are saved as UTF-8 and due to be saved as a byte string within a string, it adds extra \ etc.

I wish just the string with no additional byte string or any combination.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    bucket_iter = iter(bucket)
    while (True) : 
      next_val = next(bucket_iter)
      current_file = (next_val.get()['Body'].read())).decode('utf-8') 
      split_file = current_file.split(']')
      for tweet in split_file:
        a = tweet.split(',')
        if (len(a) == 10):
          a[0] = a[0][2:12]
          new_row = {'date':a[0], 'tweet':a[1], 'user':a[2], 'cashtags':a[3],'number_cashtags':a[4],'Hashtags':a[5],'number_hashtags':a[6],'quoted_tweet':a[7],'urs_present':a[8],'spam':a[9]}
          df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

example of a line in s3bucket

```
["2021-01-06 13:41:48", "Q1 2021 Earnings Estimate for The Walt Disney Company $DIS Issued By Truist Securiti https://t co/l5VSCCCgDF #stocks", "b'AmericanBanking'", "$DIS", "1", "#stocks'", "1", "False", "1", "0"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this is a string, it will keep the 'b' before the string, even though the item is a string. Just make a small bit of code to only keep what is inside the quotes.

```
def bytes_to_string(b):
  return str(b)[2:-1]
```

EDIT: you could technically use regexes to do this, but this is a much more readable way of doing it (and shorter)

Comment: Yeah that fixes the first problem, think for the emoj problem ill string replace \\ for \ so i have the correct Bytes (UTF-8) representation and either create dictionary of emoj's and their meaning or convert to unicode and use the python emoj library.. sounds reasonable?

Comment: yeah that sounds good. i didn't know that there was an emoji library, but assuming u turn it into proper string using the function i gave you, you can then loop through the string and find emojis, concantenating those that arent emojis to an empty string.